# The best way to create temporary folder using vimscript

Tags: vim

Is there a way to create a temporary folder using pure vim script language? I want it works on both *-nix like OS and Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order of generic to specific:

```
:help function-list
:help system-functions
:help mkdir()
:help tempname()
```